# Magento2 - Overriding magento2 backend theme

Tags: backend, magento2

How to use a new theme admin?
in Magento v1.x had to create a controller to configure a new theme.
ex:

```
` public function overrideTheme()
    {

        Mage::getDesign()->setArea('adminhtml')->setTheme('arc');
    }`
```

but I don't know how to in Magento v2.0?

Comment: Did you get an answer to your question? Can we close this?

Answer (score 1):

Was this how to create a new admin theme?  Or how to use the Admin interface to enable a theme?

If its how to create a new theme for the Admin interface in Magento 2, my advice would be "don't".

If it is how to enable a theme, go to the Admin interface and navigate Stores > Configuration > Design > Design Theme. If you have the sample data installed, you will see to themes available for your store front: Magento Blank and Magento Luma. You certainly don't have to create a Controller to do it.